# Is there a better way of managing localized strings?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resourcemanager

I work on a product where we have to worry a bit about localization. Currently, this is the workflow for when I have to use(or add) a localized string:

1. Search resources.resx file(which has hundreds of items)
2. If found, then copy the name. Otherwise, add a new string and copy the name
3. Then, use `ResourceFactory.ResourceMgr.GetString("MY_MAGIC_STRING")` (where `ResourceMgr` is just a static field to a ResourceManager)

This 3 step process for any strings is a real pain. Are there any patterns or ways to make this process easier?

Comment: Be careful about reusing the same string, there are phrases/sentences/words that have to be translated differently into other languages, depending on context. E.g. conjugation of verbs in Slavic languages depending on the subject of the sentence.

Comment: @svick of course. We usually try to keep things all together(especially by using String.Format style strings) and let the translators tell us when there's something we need to change

Comment: If this a clean code thing or make it execute faster?

Comment: @Blam for clean code primarily(though more performance never hurts)

Answer (score 5):

Auto-generated files with access to each individual string are much easier to use - set "Custom tool" for RESX file to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`.

Code would look like:

```
using MyProject.Resources;
...
localizedText = Resources.SomeReasonableName;
```

Side notes:

- having multiple RESX files along with auto-generated IDs have additional benefit of intellisense giving you reasonable number of choices.
- depending on how translation is handled you may be better not worrying about duplicated text in RESX file (except maybe OK/cancel kind of strings). It may be easier to deal with duplicated strings at translation time.

Comment: But this will only make step 3 slightly better, so it's not that big of an improvement, no?

Comment: @svick, your call. "Slightly" as in "compile time vs. run-time checks". Also if strings are organized into files by feature you get intellisense that with reasonable number of choices, if all in one file - not so much. But at least you get compile time errors instead of run-time.

Answer (score 0):

There is this Java solution that might give you some ideas:
http://rodionmoiseev.github.com/c10n/

The idea is to store translations in the source code itself, using annotations on interface methods. Then, by using a special utility, you can dynamically create proxies (classes dynamically implementing the interface) that would return localised string value when invoking the interface method.

This way, `"MY_MAGIC_STRING"` is replaced with a call to `MyMagicString()` method, which gives you some spelling/type safety and makes it more refactoring friendly.

Comment: Posting an answer that contains just a link is not very useful. Could you add a short explanation of what the library does?